# Pass Vue observable as prop?

Tags: vue.js, observable

```
var state = Vue.observable({
    selectedTab: ''
});

Vue.component('block-ui-tab', {
    props: ['name', 'handle', 'icon'],
    template: '<li :handle="handle" :class="{ active: state.selectedTab === handle }"><i :class="icon"></i>{{ name }}</li>'
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {},
    methods: {},
    computed: {},
    watch:{},
    mounted: function(){},
});
```

This doesn't work, so I'm wondering how to use the observable in the component and the vue root instance? Pass it as a prop, or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to declare `state` in the data option (see [Declaring Reactive Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties)). You can then pass it to your component.

```
Vue.component('block-ui-tab', {
    props: ['name', 'handle', 'icon', 'state'],
    template: '<li :handle="handle" :class="{ active: state.selectedTab === handle }"><i :class="icon"></i>{{ name }}</li>'
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        state: {
            selectedTab: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {},
    computed: {},
    watch:{},
    mounted: function(){},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a computed property works:

```
 computed: {
   selectedTab: function() {
     return state.selectedTab
   }
 }
```